# C# - Problem with adding users to AD groups in bulk

Tags: c#, active-directory

I work for an education organization and have written a C# program to bulk create over 20000 AD accounts for our students. The program creates the AD accounts, then iterates through them again to add them to the proper security groups, then creates home drives for them. This seems to work fine when I am only processing a low number of accounts, such as 100 or fewer. But, my organization has over 20000 accounts that need to be created in bulk every year when before the beginning of the new school year.

When I try to run the program with that many accounts to create, the accounts are created just fine. But, when it tries to add them to the AD groups,  there are some accounts that get put into the proper groups, but many do not. The end up only being put into the default Domain Users group. I am thinking this is a network latency or Domain Controller processing speed issue, but I am not sure.

Has anyone else ever experienced such a thing when creating AD accounts in bulk, regardless of programming / scripting language?

UPDATE:
Here is a the code snippet where I am adding users to groups:

static void AddUsersToGroups(List students)
{

```
        Console.WriteLine("Inside AddUserToGroups()");

        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<DOMAIN NAME GOES HERE BUT TAKEN OUT FOR THIS POST>"))
            {
                try
                {                    
                    foreach(StudentData sd in students)
                    {
                
                        if (sd.SecurityGroups.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (string grp in sd.SecurityGroups)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    GroupPrincipal secGrp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, grp.Trim());
                                    
                                    if (secGrp.Name.Equals(grp.Trim()) && secGrp.Name != null)
                                    {
                                        secGrp.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, sd.UPN.Trim());
                                        secGrp.Save();
                                        
                                    }
                                    secGrp.Dispose();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    ErrorLog el = new ErrorLog(ex, userName, region);
                                    el.InsertErrorLog(el, region);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (sd.MapDriveGroup != "")
                        {
                            GroupPrincipal mapDrive = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, sd.MapDriveGroup.Trim());
                            
                            if (mapDrive.Name.Equals(sd.MapDriveGroup.Trim()) && mapDrive.Name != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("MapDrive Group= " + sd.MapDriveGroup.Trim() + " " + mapDrive.Name);
                                mapDrive.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, sd.UPN.Trim());
                                mapDrive.Save();
                                
                            }
                            mapDrive.Dispose();

                        }

                        if (sd.PasswordGroup != "")
                        {
                            GroupPrincipal pwdGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, sd.PasswordGroup.Trim());
                           
                            if (pwdGroup.Name.Equals(sd.PasswordGroup.Trim()) && pwdGroup.Name != null)
                            {
                                pwdGroup.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, sd.UPN.Trim());
                                pwdGroup.Save();
                               

                            }
                            pwdGroup.Dispose();
                        }

                        if (sd.BrowserGroup != "")
                        {
                            GroupPrincipal browserGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, sd.BrowserGroup.Trim());
                            
                            if (browserGroup.Name.Equals(sd.BrowserGroup.Trim()) && browserGroup.Name != null)
                            {
                                browserGroup.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, sd.UPN.Trim());
                                browserGroup.Save();
                               
                            }
                            browserGroup.Dispose();
                        }
                       

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLog el = new ErrorLog(ex, userName, region);
                    el.InsertErrorLog(el, region);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog el = new ErrorLog(ex, userName, region);
            el.InsertErrorLog(el, region);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your code snippet, where you add users to groups? 
Are you using `LDAP` or `System.DirectorServices.AccountManagement`?
Do you get any errors/exceptions/logs?

Comment: Depending on how you connect, it could be that you hit a different Domain Controller when attempting to add the groups. If you've suppressed any exceptions or error handling you program might be talking to AD and getting "That user doesn't exist" because the new accounts haven't been replicated on that DC yet. This is all speculation, easier to say if you show us the code you're using :)

Comment: Posted the code that adds the accounts to groups.

Comment: I spoke with one of the Sys Admins about this the other day. He thinks it could be bottle necking where the DC does an LDAP query to add the accounts to the groups. Says it is single threaded.